# php multiple choice quiz creator

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the scenario,

At our online education firm we are creating an online quiz.
The administrator feeds in

- the question
- 1 correct answer
- 4 incorrect answers

into the mysql database using a PHP form.

Here is what the table looks like

[image]

Now I would like to do two things:

1. Make a PHP page which retrieves let's say 10 random question/answers from the table and displays it on the PHP page with radio buttons and all for a user to check the right answer.

   Can the following method be used to display retrieved info?

   `echo "<td>" . $row['question'] . "</td>";

   echo "<td>" . $row['c_answer'] . "</td>";

   echo "<td>" . $row['w_answer1'] . "</td>";

   echo "<td>" . $row['w_answer2'] . "</td>";

   echo "<td>" . $row['w_answer3'] . "</td>";

   echo "<td>" . $row['w_answer4'] . "</td>";`
2. Make a second PHP page which checks user submitted answer with the right results stored in the DB, script that checks and creates a scorecard.

How can I go about doing the 2 tasks?

All inputs appreciated.

Comment: This is really rudimentary PHP and MySQL. This isn't really a 'problem' so much as you need a ready cut 'solution'. If you don't know how to program in PHP perhaps using an existing package is more your forté?

Comment: The fact that you've tagged this question with `exam` suggests to me that these questions are directly taken from an exam paper?  Are you trying to examine us to see if we get the answers right?  Or do you have some thoughts about the answers that you'd like to check (in which case you really ought to include them in your question)?  Or do you simply have no thoughts and just want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: well jeffrey_the_wind's answer is putting me on the right track. the right answer is obviously "not many"

Comment: I know this is closed but just incase anyone is looking at that table thinking of doing anything similar DON'T. You should first normalize your data to 3nf (third normal form). So break out questions into their own table, answers in another and use a foreign key (question_id). Questions have a one to many relationship with answers, but answers would only belong to one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic HTML forms.  You have a form like this:

```
<?php
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_queryy('select * yourtable order by rand() limit 1'),MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $question = $row['question'];
    unset($row['question']);
    shuffle($row);
?>
<form method="post" action="other_script.php?q=<?php echo $question; ?>">
    <p><?php echo $question; ?></p>
    <?php
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo "<input type='radio' name='answer'>".$value."</input>
            ";
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

And then your `other_script.php` page would look like this:

```
<?php
    $ans = mysql_result(mysql_query('select c_answer from yourtable where question = "'.url_decode($_GET['q']).'"'),0);
    if ($_POST['answer'] == $ans){
        echo "You got it right!";
    }else{
        echo "You got it wrong!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: action "other_script.php?q=<?php echo $question; ?> is adding a %20 for empty spaces in question, hence get statement is not able to correctly match question with one stored in db? how can i resolve this?

Comment: Use php's url decode function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: can i send the question as a session variable instead $_session['question']=$question; and read on other end?

Comment: Yes you can do what ever you want, just remember to unset it, if it is a session var

Comment: encoding works fine, except that in all instances i am getting "you got it wrong" even when right answer is selected. any ideas?

Comment: jeffery urldecode happens automatically on the other end, the issue was with radio button generation code, it had to fixrd to echo "<input type='radio' name='answer' value='".$value."'>".$value."</input><br />";