# Comparing a value inside database with input value

Tags: php, sql, forms, if-statement

My **if statement** doesn't recognize the **textbox name ("ans")**. What should I change? and where should I put it? I also want to know if my if statement is correct; I want to compare the **value inside the database** with the **input value ("ans")**. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "avtt123");
    mysql_select_db("arvintarrega",$con);

    $sql = "SELECT * from identification";
    $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);   

    echo '<form method = "POST">';

while($iden = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
{   
    echo '<center>' . $iden['question_number'] . '. ' . $iden['statement'] . ' <input type = "text" name = "ans"></input></center></br>';

    if($iden['correct_answer'] == $_REQUEST['ans'])
       {
        echo "Correct";
       }
    else
       {
        echo "Wrong";
       } 
}   
    echo '</form>';
?>
<form method = "POST">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" class="btn btn-warning">
</form>
```

[image: Here's my database]

Comment: Can we see your form?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Also use `isset()` inside and in conjunction with `if($iden['correct_answer'] == $_REQUEST['ans'])`. You also don't have a submit button.

Comment: You're also using the wrong variable `while($iden = mysql_fetch_array($myData))` <===

Comment: @D4V1D The form is inside the PHP code

Comment: I copied the wrong variable inside the while loop. My bad/

Comment: @Fred-ii- It still doesnt recognize the variable 'ans'

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['ans']) && $iden['correct_answer'] == $_POST['ans'])`

Comment: It echos "Wrong" even though the correct answer as the input value @Fred-ii-

Comment: It's hard to follow your code and which row you're trying to get a right answer from. How many fields are supposed to show up, one or many?

Comment: I can't help you any further if you're not going to answer my last question. I've successfully tested your code with a few modifications. Other than not knowing what field or number of fields, then I can be of no further help. Good luck with finding the reason why your code is failing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I inserted an image

Comment: The correct_answer comes from the database.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I've a solution almost ready for you.

Comment: I've posted something for you below in the answers area.

Comment: I'm not sure if you seen/tried what I posted below, but since I didn't hear anything from you in almost a half hour, am under the impression that you're building a multi-quiz with more than one question and that what I posted has failed for you; am I correct? My answer below addresses what you posted in your question, and not for multiple questions/answers in your table.

Comment: What if I want multiple questions? What should I add from what you gave me?

Comment: @Noobist To be honest, I've never had to build quiz codes before. However, you can have a look at this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/12136151/ which could give you some ideas as well as this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/10356623/ - These were found after Googling "quiz mysql php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the following a try which worked for me, and I'm using a `mysqli_` connection and query, so change the `xxx` with your own credentials.

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = 'xxx';
$DB_USER = 'xxx';
$DB_PASS = 'xxx';
$DB_NAME = 'xxx';

$Link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($Link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $Link->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT * from identification LIMIT 1";

$myData = mysqli_query($Link, $sql);   

    echo '<form method = "POST">';

while($iden = mysqli_fetch_array($myData))
{
    echo '<center>' . $iden['question_number'] . '. ' . $iden['statement'] . ' <input type = "text" name = "ans"></center><br/>';

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

    if(isset($_POST['ans']) && $iden['correct_answer'] == $_POST['ans']){

      echo "Correct<br><br>";
       }
    else
       {
        echo "Wrong<br><br>";
       } 


    } // if(isset($_POST['submit'])) end brace

} // while loop end brace

echo '<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" class="btn btn-warning">';

     echo '</form>';
?>
```